# How to gnuplot a candlestick plot with whiskers using data from the STATS command of GNUPLOT?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a big data file, where I only want to compute statistics for one column and then plot the resulting stats in a candlestick plot with whiskers.

Is this possible?
How?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
tmp_data = ""
stats filename . '.csv' using 21

tmp_data = tmp_data.sprintf("%i %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %s\n", n, STATS_min, STATS_lo_quartile, STATS_mean, STATS_up_quartile, STATS_max, STATS_median, 0.5, filename)

set print 'temp.dat'
print tmp_data
unset print
```

That way I just print the data from `stats` to a temporal file and I plot that data.